# gomobile bind: missing methods with struct and interface parameters

Tags: android, go, gomobile

I have the following go code:

```
package hello

import (
    "TestGoMobile/model"
    "fmt"
)

func Test(string) int {
    return 0
}

func Greetings(test model.Test) string {
    return test.Name
}

func Hello(base model.Base) {
    fmt.Println("hello world!")
}
```

```
package model

type Test struct {
    Name string
}

type Base interface {
    OnError(errCode int32, errMsg string)
    OnSuccess(data string)
}
```

when I run: gomobile bind -target=android ./hello

I got the following result:

```
package hello;

import go.Seq;

public abstract class Hello {
    private Hello() {
    }

    public static void touch() {
    }

    private static native void _init();

    public static native long test(String var0);

    static {
        Seq.touch();
        _init();
    }
}
```

**The methods Greetings and Hello have not been generated successfully.**

This seems to be related to the method's struct parameters and interface parameters.

And here is the link to the type restrictions of gomobile, but unfortunately it doesn't help me.

> https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind#hdr-Type_restrictions

Can you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
// hello.go
// like this...
type Test model.Test
func Greetings(test Test) string {
    return test.Name
}
//...
```